# Solution for $y''+4y'+8y=x+e^x$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this ODE?

$$y''+4y'+8y=x+e^x$$

After I find the roots of the characteristic and create the solution for the homogeneous, how can I find the solution for this ODE?

Comment: The Laplace-Transform would be a nice method I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach:
Having a nonhomogeneous equation you must determine the homogeneous part and a particular solution:

We write as follows $y=y_h+y_p,$ where $y_h$ is the solution of the homogeneous equation and $y_p$ is a particular solution.

As you said, using the characteristic polynomial we get the roots: $-2+2i$ and $-2-2i.$

So the solution of the homogeneous equation will be: $y_h(x)=c_1e^{-2x}cos(2x)+c_2e^{-2x}sin(2x).$

Now it is up to us to finish the particular solution. Because your equation has an expression like that $x+e^x$ in the right side, you can try to find a solution in the form of: a first degree polynomial plus an exponential function. Something like this: $y_p(x)=Ax+B+Ce^x.$
Put this particular solution in your equation, force it to check your equation and find the coefficients.
After you have found the coefficients replace them in the expression for $y_p$.

After all this, combine the two solutions $y_h$ and $y_p$ and so we have the final solution of the equation.
If you need more explanations you can write a comment.

Comment: Thanks you! =) .

Comment: That was really perfect. Thank you for spending time with me! :)
I'm gonna try this. :D

Comment: With pleasure! Good luck!

Comment: It worked! :) :D

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Find a particular polynomial solution $ y_1$ of the equation

$$y''+4y'+8y=x$$

and a particular solution $ y_2=z_2e^x$ of
$$y''+4y'+8y=e^x$$

and sum them to get a particular solution $ y_p $.

The general solution is $$ y_g=y_h+y_p$$
$y_h $ is your homogeneous solution.

You should find that
$$y_p=\frac{2x-1}{16}+\frac{e^x}{13}$$

Comment: Nice one! Thank you! :)